# How to setup one instance of Kontakt to use more than one virtual instruments to their own outputs

Tags: plugins, reaper, setup, kontakt

So as far as using one MIDI channel per instruments, I understand that (somewhat). But how to route their output to individual channels in Reaper is a bit beyond me.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or should I be running a new instance of Kontakt for each instruments? I'm thinking that would be very inefficient.

I'm using Kontakt 5, but I'm pretty sure it has similar routing capabilities as Kontakt 4.

The host DAW I'm using is Reaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! Here's a good answer from someone who had the same frustration as I experienced: